# Multiple SUM's in a SELECT but on one view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've written a `select` statement to assist with timesheet approval. It show's the summation of hours entered against a user based on different roles booked, i.e. Standard Office Hours, Overtime, Holiday & Offshore.

I want a single row per `[Name]` but I get a row for every `SUM` where the user has data.

Do I need to create this as a view and `SELECT` to that view?

My current code is below:

```
SELECT 
    TSDEPT_HEAD As [Resource],
    CONCAT (PP_FIRST_NAME,' ',PP_SURNAME) As [Name],    
    SUM(Case WHEN TST_ROLE = 'STD' Then TST_HOURS END) As STD, 
    SUM(Case WHEN TST_ROLE LIKE 'OT%' Then TST_HOURS END) As OT,
    SUM(Case WHEN TST_ROLE LIKE 'OFF%' Then TST_HOURS END) As OFFSHORE,
    SUM(Case WHEN TST_ROLE = 'HOL' Then TST_HOURS END) As HOL
    FROM TS_TIMESHEETS
LEFT JOIN SYS_PEOPLE on TST_RESOURCE = PP_CODE
LEFT JOIN TS_USERS on TST_RESOURCE = TSU_USERID
LEFT JOIN TS_DEPARTMENTS on TSU_DEPARTMENT_CODE = TSDEPT_CODE
WHERE MONTH(TST_DATE) = MONTH(GETDATE())
GROUP BY TSDEPT_NAME,TST_ROLE,PP_FIRST_NAME,PP_SURNAME,TST_RESOURCE,PP_KNOWN_AS,TSDEPT_HEAD
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` groups rows by the expressions after it, according to its name

Comment: Why are you grouping on columns that aren't in your `SELECT`? Also, don't use syntax like `WHERE MONTH(TST_DATE) = MONTH(GETDATE())`; it's not SARGable. Instead use inclusive date logic (using `>=` and `<`). Also do you *really* want data for every February, regardless of the year?

Comment: You need to modify your `GROUP BY` and group only by the columns you need, in this case `GROUP BY TSDEPT_NAME,PP_FIRST_NAME,PP_SURNAME`

Comment: Do you realize that filtering based on month alone will combine rows from different years (but same month)? Your query many only **appear** to work correctly if your test data is sufficiently varied to validate your logic.

Comment: @Smor. I had added a Year(TST_DATE) = Year(GETDATE()) to my where clause. This only went live in January but yes, would have been interesting in 12 months time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just use the group by for the columns you really want aggregate, tipilcally the same columns you have in select but not with an aggreagtion functions

```
SELECT 
TSDEPT_HEAD As [Resource],
CONCAT (PP_FIRST_NAME,' ',PP_SURNAME) As [Name],    
SUM(Case WHEN TST_ROLE = 'STD' Then TST_HOURS END) As STD, 
SUM(Case WHEN TST_ROLE LIKE 'OT%' Then TST_HOURS END) As OT,
SUM(Case WHEN TST_ROLE LIKE 'OFF%' Then TST_HOURS END) As OFFSHORE,
SUM(Case WHEN TST_ROLE = 'HOL' Then TST_HOURS END) As HOL
FROM TS_TIMESHEETS
LEFT JOIN SYS_PEOPLE on TST_RESOURCE = PP_CODE
LEFT JOIN TS_USERS on TST_RESOURCE = TSU_USERID
LEFT JOIN TS_DEPARTMENTS on TSU_DEPARTMENT_CODE = TSDEPT_CODE
WHERE MONTH(TST_DATE) = MONTH(GETDATE())
GROUP BY     TSDEPT_HEAD, CONCAT (PP_FIRST_NAME,' ',PP_SURNAME)
```

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY [Name]` only - the sum statements are aggregates, so don't need to be included in the group clause. This will give you one row for each person, based on the [Name] column.